# f# writing custom fold function to perform operations like additions

Tags: list, recursion, f#, fold

I am relatively new to F# (Have worked on C#, Java & C++). Instead of using List.fold function, I want to create my own Fold function, say myCustomFold. The intended output might be:

`myCustomFold (+) 0 [1; 2; 3 ]` will return 6.

any hints or ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: Hints: pattern matching and recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for some syntax hints. Something like this maybe:

```
let rec myCustomFold f s0 =
  function
  | [] -> s0
  | x::tail -> myCustomFold f (f s0 x) tail
```